# Intersection of curves?

Tags: calculus

The book says one set of points is (1,2) for the intersection of curves a) $y^2=4x$ b) $2x^2 = 12-5y$.

It says that tan (symbol of an O with a line through it) = 9. I understand the calculation, but I don't know what the symbol is called.

I don't understand how the answer is "(symbol of an O with a line through it) 83 degrees 40' is the acute angle."

Where do 83 and 40 come from?

Comment: The symbol "O with a line through it" is called phi. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi

Comment: The angle 83º 40' given is the (lesser) angle made between the tangent lines to each curve at that intersection point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two curves $y=f(x)=2\sqrt{x}$ and $y=g(x)=\dfrac{2}{5}(6-x^2)$ intersect in $(1;2)$, with

$f'(1)=1=\tan a$ (thus $a=\pi/4\approx 0.7854$) and

$b=g'(1)=-4/5=\tan b$ (thus $b\approx-0.6747$).

Therefore, the acute angle between the tangents at that point is angle $a-b \approx 1.4601$.

If one desires a neater expression for $a-b$:

$$\tan(a-b)=\dfrac{\tan a - \tan b}{1+\tan a \tan b}=\dfrac{1+4/5}{1-4/5}=9$$

The answer is thus  $atan(9)$ when expressed in radians and $atan(9)\times(180/\pi)$ when converted into degrees, i.e., $\approx 83.66$ degrees, approximatively $83$ degrees and $2/3$ degree $=40'$ (see picture).

[image]

Comment: I think you want the arctangent of 9 for that angle; the ratio you have requires a little additional interpretation.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Yes its a stupid mistake. Thanks. I correct it

Comment: The idea isn't wrong and I got the same ratio.  But you need to say a bit more about how to interpret the angles you call $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ in this ratio. (There is an issue with the quadrants each is in.)

Comment: According to the book, your answer is right. I multiplied 1/9 and 180/pi and got 6.36. Why is that? Also, where does "2/3 degree = 40'" come from?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner  You are right: it wouldn't be the first time that it is lengthy to write down a perfectly rigorous treatment when dealing with angles... and the quadrants where they "live"... A solution is to give the two solutions : the acute AND the obtuse angle.

Comment: I had not read precisely what you were asking : the right computation (I had made a silly error) is $atan(9)\times(180/\pi)=83.6598 \approx 83,6666=83+2/3$.  "2/3 degree = 40'=40 minutes" because there are 60 minutes in a degree (like for hours)

Comment: Could you explain how you get 83.65? When I multiplied 9 x 180, then divided by pi, I get 515.66.

Comment: It is atan(9) that is multiplied by $180/\pi$.